# How to use the kendo-ui menu control with angular 2?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Looking at the list of Kendo UI controls for Angular 2 [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/),  it seems that the Kendo UI menu control is not yet supported with Angular 2. Will it be supported in the future? If yes when? This is an essential navigation component, I would have thought that it would be supported early in the Angular 2 releases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your request in our [feedback portal](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback).